# pandas: How to speed up a loop including spliting column and adding maximum element to new columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, optimization, split

I am struggling with speeding up my code. My code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({ 'line':["320000-320000, 340000-320000, 320000-340000",
                            "380000-320000",
                            "380000-320000,380000-310000",
                            "370000-320000,370000-320000,320000-320000",
                            "320000-320000, 340000-320000, 320000-340000",
                           ], 'id':[1,2,3,4,5,],})

def most_common(lst):
    return max(set(lst), key=lst.count)

def split_list(lines):
    return '-'.join('%s' % id for id in lines).split('-')

df['line']=df['line'].str.split(',')
col_ix=df['line'].index.values
df['line_start'] = pd.Series(0, index=df.index)
df['line_destination'] = pd.Series(0, index=df.index)

import time 
start = time.clock()

for ix in col_ix:
    col = df['line'][ix]
    col_split = split_list(col)
    even_col_split = col_split[0:][::2]
    even_col_split_most = most_common(even_col_split)
    df['line_start'][ix] = even_col_split_most

    odd_col_split = col_split[1:][::2]

    odd_col_split_most = most_common(odd_col_split)
    df['line_destination'][ix] = odd_col_split_most

end = time.clock()
print('time\n',str(end-start))
del df['line']
```

What I want to do is,firstly,spliting the column `line` according to `-`; secondly,spliting the `line` into two columns according to parity index; thirdly,finding the maximum element of the two columns.

`Input`:

```
df
    id                                         line
0   1  320000-320000, 340000-320000, 320000-340000
1   2                                380000-320000
2   3                  380000-320000,380000-310000
3   4    370000-320000,370000-320000,320000-320000
4   5  320000-320000, 340000-320000, 320000-340000
```

Spliting df according to `-`:

```
df
    id                                               line
0   1  [320000, 320000,  340000, 320000,  320000, 340000]
1   2                                   [380000, 320000]
2   3                   [380000, 320000, 380000, 310000]
3   4   [370000, 320000, 370000, 320000, 320000, 320000]
4   5  [320000, 320000,  340000, 320000,  320000, 340000]
```

Spliting df according to parity index:

```
df
    id                                               line  \
0   1  [320000, 320000,  340000, 320000,  320000, 340000]
1   2                                   [380000, 320000]
2   3                   [380000, 320000, 380000, 310000]
3   4   [370000, 320000, 370000, 320000, 320000, 320000]
4   5  [320000, 320000,  340000, 320000,  320000, 340000]

                   line_start          line_destination
0  [320000,  340000,  320000]  [320000, 320000, 340000]
1                    [380000]                  [320000]
2            [380000, 380000]          [320000, 310000]
3    [370000, 370000, 320000]  [320000, 320000, 320000]
4  [320000,  340000,  320000]  [320000, 320000, 340000]
```

Find the maximum element of column `line_start` and `line_destination` and del `line` (also my `Output`):

```
df
    id  line_start  line_destination
0   1      320000            320000
1   2      380000            320000
2   3      380000            310000
3   4      370000            320000
4   5      320000            320000
```

Now I would expect a way to complete the task faster.

Comment: Your output for `line_destination` seems to be incorrect based on your rules and second to last `df`

Comment: Or do you mean `mode` instead of `max`? Still not sure how you get 31k for `id=3` regardless

Comment: Sorry for misleading you. The `max` can be understood as `most`,which means the number appears most. As you can see, for `id=3`,31k count 1 and 32k also count 1, then the function `max` return the the first one of the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one option:

- Start by splitting your input lists and expanding to a `DataFrame`.
- We'll stack it so we can easily group and calculate `max` for the groups we define below.
- Then we need to find the `parity` for each group by modulus.
- Find the max value within each index and the above parity group
- Rename, and pivot to your desired output.

Here's the code:

```
import pandas as pd
#import scipy.stats as stats  # if you meant 'mode'
#import numpy as np  # if you meant 'mode'

df1 = df.line.str.split('-|,').apply(pd.Series).stack().reset_index()

# Determine the parity for each line
df1['level_1'] = df1.level_1%2

# Determine the max for each id-parity group and rename properly
df1[0]= pd.to_numeric(df1[0])  # So max works properly

df1 = df1.groupby(['level_0', 'level_1'])[0].max().reset_index()
# If you instead meant 'mode' replace the above with this:
#df1 = df1.groupby(['level_0', 'level_1'])[0].apply(lambda x: stats.mode(np.sort(x))[0][0]).reset_index()

df1['level_1'] = df1.level_1.map({0: 'line_start', 1: 'line_destination'})

# Pivot to the form you want, bring back the index
df1 = df1.pivot(index= 'level_0', columns='level_1', values=0)
df1['id'] = df.id  #aligns on index, which was preserved 
df1.index.name=None
df1.columns.name=None
```

---

`df1` is now your desired  (at least based on your stated rules):

```
   line_destination  line_start  id
0            340000      340000   1
1            320000      380000   2
2            320000      380000   3
3            320000      370000   4
4            340000      340000   5
```

---

Here's the result using the `mode` instead of `max`. Note, I had to sort before taking the mode to get the desired output of 31,000 when there was a tie.

```
   line_destination  line_start  id
0            320000      320000   1
1            320000      380000   2
2            310000      380000   3
3            320000      370000   4
4            320000      320000   5
```